# Show that $dF_x$ is surjective for all $x$

Tags: differential-topology

I am trying to tackle question 2.3.8 on GP, but I haven't figure out the following question yet.

Suppose $m > 1$. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth map. Consider $f + Ax$ for $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n}$. Define $F: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n} \rightarrow \mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n}$ by $F(x,A) = df_x + A$. How can I show that $dF_x$ is surjective for all $x$?

I am really grateful to @Ross B. 's answer on the question [The derivative of a linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417643/the-derivative-of-a-linear-transformation?noredirect=1#comment893154_417643), $DF$ would be a rank-3 tensor with elements

$$
(DF)_{i,j,k} = \frac{\partial^2 f_i}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}
$$

Some authors also define matrix-by-vector and matrix-by-matrix derivatives differently be considering $m \times n$ matricies as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ and "stacking" the resulting partial derivatives.

Then I got really lost trying to show that $dF$ is surjective.

Some thoughts I had so far:

$f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, and its tangent plane has dimension $m \times n$, therefore $dF$ maps from $m \times n \times n$ to $m \times n$. Then I am thinking of to prove that $\forall m \in \mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n}, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}^n, A \in \mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n}$ such that $ d f_x + A = m$. I am not sure if this is correct, nor how to prove this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: *To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far*. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Hi @ZevChonoles, thanks a lot for your instruction. I added where the problem comes from and why I got stuck. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think $m=n$ for the problem?

Comment: Oh exactly @Matt... =)

Comment: No, if you look at the function $g\colon M(n)\to M(n)$, $g(A)=A$, what's the derivative?

Comment: @Matt I mean, GP says m=n, but the problem I am dealing with is $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ - thanks!

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, I guess I got confused again - the derivative of linear transformation is itself.... right? Thank you -)

Comment: @TedShifrin So, is it $dF(x,A)=d(dfx+A)=d^2f_x+A$ then?

Comment: I guess I was really hungry earlier..I think it should be $dF(x,A) = d(df_x + A) = df_x + A$

Comment: What happens if $n<m$ and $A=0$?

Comment: @Matt Hope that won't happen? I assumed $n > m, A \neq 0$...

Comment: No, it's not $df_x + A$. Don't write down this formal formulas without understanding what you're doing :) If you want to show $dF_{(x,A)}\colon \mathbb R^n \times M(n) \to M(n)$ is surjective, think about an appropriate directional derivative that will give you what you want. That is, you need to think about $dF_{(x,A)}(v,B)$ and what you know and what you don't.

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin, thank you so much for helping me again and again.. Though, I am curious that if it is not $df_x +A$, what it could be? $df_x$ is linear, and $A$ is a matrix, I don't understand where could be wrong.. :)

Comment: What is $f$? A linear map?

Comment: @BenjaLim " 千里之行，始于足下" - 老子。 ;)

Comment: @BenjaLim In the problem, it is given that $f$ is a smooth map (I just added this in the problem description.) But to my understanding, $df_x$ is a linear map, since it works on the tangent plane - or this is not true..?

Comment: @MathSnail Yes that is true. The derivative is a linear map between two finite dimensional vector spaces. Perhaps you should have said more explicitly in the beginning of the question that $f$ is ***any*** smooth map.

Comment: Hint: $f$ is actually irrelevant for this proposition/proof. Follow my advice and do directional derivatives, not in coordinates.

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin, I have been thinking hard on the directional derivatives and made some progress as edited in the question. But I still could not draw the conclusion. Would you mind kindly giving me some help? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is $dF_{(x,A)}(0,B)$ for any $m\times n$ matrix $B$? BTW, GP 2.3.8 specifically has $n\times n$ matrices. To get from $F$ a submersion to $F_A$ never $0$ for generic $A$ you will need $m\times n$ with $m>1$.

Comment: Hi Ted, I guess I am dealing with a slight derivation of 2.3.8..

Comment: I guess $dF_{x,A}(0,B) = d_{x,A}(df_x+A) = d^2f_x + dA_A = d^2f_x + I_A = d^2f_x + A$..?

Comment: No. Please use the definition of the derivative of a map between vector spaces: $dg_a(v) = \lim\limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{g(a+tv)-g(a)}t$.

Comment: Thank you Ted. $\displaystyle dF_{x,A}(0,B) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{F(x,A+tB)-F(x,A)}{t}= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{df_x + A+ tB-df_x - A}{t}= B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question arises many very interesting discussions: like
[The dimension of the derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417821/the-dimension-of-the-derivative/418031?noredirect=1#418031) and [The derivative of a linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417643/the-derivative-of-a-linear-transformation?noredirect=1#comment893154_417643). These discussions are really very helpful and inspiring for me. Thanks all the wonderful teachers!

However, the solution to show that $dF_x$ is surjective for all $x$ is rather straight forward, thanks to Professor @Ted Shifirin's patient guidance. I hope I carried out Ted's beautiful proof correctly:

Consider $\displaystyle dF_{x,A}(0,B) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{F(x,A+tB)-F(x,A)}{t}= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{df_x + A+ tB-df_x - A}{t}= B$. Therefore, $\forall m \in \mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n}, \exists B \in \mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n}$, such that $dF_{x,A}(0,B) = m$. In particular, $B=m$.