# The derivative of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $m > 1$. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth map. Consider $f + Ax$ for $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n}, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Define $F: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n} \rightarrow \mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n}$ by $F(x,A) = df_x + A$.

So what is $dF_x$?

(A) Is it $dF(x,A) = d(df_x + A) = d f_x + A$? And therefore,

$$dF(x,A) =\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} \\
\vdots &  & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}\end{array} \right) + 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1m} \\
\vdots &  & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nm}\end{array} \right)$$

(B) Or should it be $dF(x,A) = d(df_x + A) = d^2 f_x + I$? And therefore,

$$dF(x,A) =\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial^2 f_1}{\partial x_1^2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial^2 f_m}{\partial x_1^2} \\
\vdots &  & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial^2 f_1}{\partial x_n^2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial^2 f_m}{\partial x_n^2}\end{array} \right) + 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots &  & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 1\end{array} \right)$$

Does this look right? Thank you very much.

Comment: You seem to be using $x$ for two different things in the same equation...

Comment: I am afraid, the RHS in the last expression does not make sense.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Thanks so much Daniel. The $x_i$s in the first matrix intended to be basis. I changed to $e_i$s. Is it look alright now?

Comment: Thank you @Vishal. I modified. Does it make sense now? (Not necessarily correct though..)

Comment: The domain of $F$ is $\mathbb{R}^n \times \operatorname{Mat}_{m \times n}$, so if you're writing $dF_x(v)$, then $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \operatorname{Mat}_{m \times n}$, and $v \in T_x(\mathbb{R}^n \times \operatorname{Mat}_{m \times n})$, which is an $(n + mn)$-dimensional space.

Comment: You have not made any changes concerning my objection. One of the terms is a vector and the other is a matrix and you want to add them!

Comment: Thanks @DanielMcLaury that makes it clear. I was intended to write down the matrix of $df$ at $x$, I hope now I got it right.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the derivative of $f$ or the derivative of $F$?

Comment: Oh no angry mathematician. I realized where I was wrong, I hope I got it right now. Thank you @Vishal.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury thank you. I am trying to calculate the derivative of $F$. And since $df_x$ and $A$ are linear transformations, I thought $dF$ just equals to $F$. I am not confident with this though.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "consider $f + A x$" here.  What is $x$?  A vector?  A scalar?

Comment: Hi @DanielMcLaury thank you.  $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ - I added it in the description.

Comment: Well, in that case $f$ is a function and $A x$ is a vector, so what on earth does $f + A x$ mean?

Comment: Hi @DanielMcLaury I was given that.. But I guess I don't need that information, and just use $F = df_x + A$. In this case, $f$ is a smooth function and $df_x$ is a $m \times n$-dimensional linear transformation; $A$ is also a $m \times n$-dimensional linear transformation. So we can add $df_x$ and $A$ then?

Comment: Your grand formula is wrong. As the definition of $F$ involves $df$ the derivative of $F$ will involve second derivatives of $f$.

Comment: Furthermore, would $DF_x$ not be a rank-3 tensor?

Comment: Thank you Professor @ChristianBlatter. I confused with "the derivative of a linear function is itself". I add "thought B" in the question - is it what it suppose to be? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @RossB. sorry I don't understand what do you mean.... Could you explain...? Thank you.

Comment: As you have defined it, $F$ is a matrix-valued function. Therefore, the derivative would require three indicies--taking the derivative of component $(F)_{i,j}$ with respect to component $x_k$.

Comment: Hi @RossB. thanks for your response. I added "thought B" - does it look more correct to you...?

Comment: I don't believe either are correct, for the reason stated above. Also keep in mind that there are unfortunately many different notations and subtleties regarding matrix derivatives.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9205/discussion-between-mathsnail-and-ross-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, by your definition, $F$ is a matrix-valued function, $DF$ would be a rank-3 tensor with elements

$$
(DF)_{i,j,k} = \frac{\partial^2 f_i(x)}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}
$$

Some authors also define matrix-by-vector and matrix-by-matrix derivatives differently be considering $m \times n$ matricies as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ and "stacking" the resulting partial derivatives.

See [this paper](http://janmagnus.nl/papers/JRM093.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Ah now I got what you say - thank you!